# Hive Table returning empty result set on all queries

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I created a Hive Table, which loads data from a text file. But its returning empty result set on all queries.

I tried the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE table2(
id1 INT,
id2 INT,
id3 INT,
id4 STRING,
id5 INT,
id6 STRING,
id7 STRING,
id8 STRING,
id9 STRING,
id10 STRING,
id11 STRING,
id12 STRING,
id13 STRING,
id14 STRING,
id15 STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/biadmin/lineitem';
```

The command gets executed, and the table gets created. But, always returns 0 rows for all queries, including `SELECT * FROM table2;`

Sample data:

Single line of the input data:

1|155190|7706|1|17|21168.23|0.04|0.02|N|O|1996-03-13|1996-02-12|1996-03-22|DELIVER IN PERSON|TRUCK|egular courts above the|

I have attached the screen shot of the data file. 
Output for command: DESCRIBE FORMATTED table2;

```
| Wed Apr 16 20:18:58 IST 2014 : Connection obtained for host: big-instght-15.persistent.co.in, port number 1528. |
| # col_name                    data_type                   comment                                               |
|                                                                                                                 |
| id1                         int                         None                                                    |
| id2                         int                         None                                                    |
| id3                         int                         None                                                    |
| id4                         string                      None                                                    |
| id5                         int                         None                                                    |
| id6                         string                      None                                                    |
| id7                         string                      None                                                    |
| id8                         string                      None                                                    |
| id9                         string                      None                                                    |
| id10                        string                      None                                                    |
| id11                        string                      None                                                    |
| id12                        string                      None                                                    |
| id13                        string                      None                                                    |
| id14                        string                      None                                                    |
| id15                        string                      None                                                    |
|                                                                                                                 |
| # Detailed Table Information                                                                                    |
| Database:                   default                                                                             |
| Owner:                      biadmin                                                                             |
| CreateTime:                 Mon Apr 14 20:17:31 IST 2014                                                        |
| LastAccessTime:             UNKNOWN                                                                             |
| Protect Mode:               None                                                                                |
| Retention:                  0                                                                                   |
| Location:                   hdfs://big-instght-11.persistent.co.in:9000/user/biadmin/lineitem                 |
| Table Type:                 MANAGED_TABLE                                                                       |
| Table Parameters:                                                                                               |
|         serialization.null.format                                                                               |
|         transient_lastDdlTime        1397486851                                                                 |
|                                                                                                                 |
| # Storage Information                                                                                           |
| SerDe Library:              org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe                                  |
| InputFormat:                org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat                                            |
| OutputFormat:               org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat                          |
| Compressed:                 No                                                                                  |
| Num Buckets:                -1                                                                                  |
| Bucket Columns:             []                                                                                  |
| Sort Columns:               []                                                                                  |
| Storage Desc Params:                                                                                            |
|         field.delim                 |                                                                          |
```

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Thanks!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Could you please show me your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that the location **/user/biadmin/lineitem.txt** actually exists and you have data present there. Since you are using **LOCATION** clause your data must be present there, instead of the default warehouse location, **/user/hive/warehouse**.

Do a quick **ls** to verify that :

```
bin/hadoop fs -ls /user/biadmin/lineitem.txt
```

Also, make sure that you are using the proper **delimiter**.

Comment: Could you please let me know what exactly you did? Also, it would be helpful if you could show me a record of your data, if possible.

Comment: I just added a small sample of the input data to the question.

Comment: Thank you. This is strange. Everything looks fine. Could you please show me the output of **describe formatted table2** command?

Comment: Hi Tariq, I have added the output of describe formatted table2.

Comment: Hi @MahalakshmiLakshminarayanan..Sorry for the late response. This looks fine..What does **hadoop fs -ls /user/biadmin/lineitem** show??

Comment: Actually, I opened it. I didn't have anything in it. It was a drwxr-xr-x file.

Comment: Yeah..This was the first thing which came to my mind after looking at your question. Glad that you got it working :)

Comment: I also had a linitem.txt file in the hdfs. When I set the location to point to the file, I got the error: Parent Path is not a directory.Then I put the file in the directory tpc-h and gave the path of the directory in the location while creating the table and it worked.

Comment: Exactly. When you use the **location** clause, it is expected that the provided path is a directory. And all the files under this directory collectively constitute the data for that particular table. You don't have to specify the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE'/user/biadmin/lineitem.txt' INTO TABLE table2 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(id1,id2,id3........);
```

Documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: I tried the above command, but I get the error: keyword hbase or hive expected.

Comment: i also tried the equivalent hive command.. i got the error mentioned in the above command. I tried the command: LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/user/biadmin/lineitem.txt' INTO TABLE table2;

Answer (score 0):

Are you using managed table or external table?? If it is external table you should use external keyword while creating the table. after creating the table load data into the table using load command. if it is managed table, after loading data to the table, you could see the data in your hive warehouse directory in hadoop. the default path is "/user/hive/warehouse/yourtablename".
you should run the load command in the hive shell.

Comment: The question clearly shows that it's a managed table. And since she is using the **location** clause, the data will not be there at the default location.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to load the data to the table.  The problem was:

LOCATION '/user/biadmin/lineitem';

wasn't loading any data. But when I gave the directory containing the file as the path like:

LOCATION '/user/biadmin/tpc-h';

where I put the lineite.txt file in the tpc-h directory.

It worked!